# Create ATM Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am trying to create ATM algorithm. The logic is as follows
There are 3 Denominations `100,500,1000`

When the Amount is 100 the output is `Print 1 100 Note`

When the Amount is 500 the output is `Print 5 100 Note`

When the Amount is 1000 the output is `Print 1 500 Note` and `Print 5 100 Note`

So When the amount is 4500 the output  should be

`3 1000 Note`

`2 500 Note`

`5 100 Note`

My algorithm is as follows

```
   int _remainingamt = _inputAmt / 1000;

        if (_remainingamt > 1)
        {
            _inputAmt = _inputAmt - (_remainingamt-1) * 1000;
            Console.WriteLine("Print {0} 1000 Notes", _remainingamt - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            _inputAmt = _inputAmt - _remainingamt * 1000;
            Console.WriteLine("Print {0} 1000 Notes", _remainingamt);
        }

        _remainingamt = _inputAmt / 500;
        if (_remainingamt > 1)
        {
            _inputAmt = _inputAmt - (_remainingamt - 1) * 500;
            Console.WriteLine("Print {0} 500 Notes", _remainingamt - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            _inputAmt = _inputAmt - _remainingamt * 500;
            Console.WriteLine("Print {0} 500 Notes", _remainingamt);
        }

        _remainingamt = _inputAmt / 100;
        _inputAmt = _inputAmt - _remainingamt*100;
        if (_remainingamt!=0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Print {0} 100 Notes", _remainingamt);    
        }
```

The logic here is 
the first `500` of the amount should be `100 Notes` or `Notes`

The next 500(if remaining in the amount) should be `500 Note` or `Notes`

The next 1000( if remaining in the amount) should be `1000 Note` or `Notes`

but i still face problems with certain amounts.

Can anyone help please

Thank You All

Comment: on 1000, why wouldnt you print `2 500 note`?

Comment: `>` should be `>=` maybe?   This might be a good candidate for the "code-trolling" tag on codegolf.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @paqogomez For the same reason it prints 5 `100 note` when the amount is 500 I'm guessing.

Comment: Can you give us some example input with expected **and actual** output, so we can see what the actual problem is? Also, a few strategic print statements, or debugging your code should tell you the problem quick enough.

Comment: What should the output be for 1600?

Comment: @itsme86, Very true.  Whatever that reason, i cant see how it would be a good one tho.

Comment: There is no question here. This is not a service for debugging your assignments. Ask a specific question about the code.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple program that will do what you are looking for.  I'm not sure what values you are sending that is giving you problems, but for the little bit of testing I did, i couldnt find any.

You did say that for 1000 you wanted 1 500 and 5 100's.  As an ATM would always dispense the largest bills it could, I figured this must be in error, let me know if i'm incorrect.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var inputAmount = 4500;
    var intervals = new[] {100, 500, 1000};

    if (inputAmount%100 != 0)
    {
        Console.Write("Only bills of in increments of 100 are dispensed");
        return;
    }

    foreach (var interval in intervals.OrderByDescending(e => e))
    {
        int count = inputAmount/interval;
        inputAmount = inputAmount%interval;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} Note", count, interval);
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

This output is:

> 4 1000 Note
>
> 1 500 Note
>
> 0 100 Note